# Alert/Report on any permission change in SharePoint Environment

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, alert, changelog, getchanges

I have a SharePoint farm as well as a SharePoint online tenant which need to monitor for any permission change.

I want some alert that will be trigger a email and notify any change in farm or tenant level in SharePoint. May it item level permission or site collection level.

or if not an alert then a daily / weekly report will suffice the need.

Answer (score -1):

Currently we could only create alert based on item changed rather than permission changed.

More information:

https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-create-sharepoint-alerts/

Comment: This I know very well, that is why I raised my query to find, if there is any workaround.

Comment: As a workaround, we could run audit report about permission changed in SharePoint on-premise:

https://www.lepide.com/how-to/audit-permission-changes-in-sharepoint-2013.html